# how to write format to fscanf in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have something like that:

```
1  1  1 2 3 10 17 16 15 8 9 
2  1  3 4 5 12 19 18 17 10 11
3  1  5 6 7 4 21 20 19 12 13
4  1  15 16 17 24 31 30 29 22 23
```

1st column : number
2nd column : mode
3rd-12st column : point

I wrote this `fscan`'s format.

```
for no=1:4    
    no=fscanf(FID5, '%d', 1);
    mode=fscanf(FID5, '%d', 1);
    point=fscanf(FID5, '%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d',[9,1]);

    fprintf(FID6, '%-2d           %-2d        %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d  %-2d\n',no,mode,point); 

end
```

I expect:

```
point=size(no,9)
```

but
I got

```
point=size(1,9)
```

Could you tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problems in your solution

Let's try to fix your current solution: The main problem is that you're reading only one row of values into `points` in each iteration, overwriting whatever has been stored in it before. Try modifying your code like so:

```
point = zeros(4, 9);  %// Add this line to preallocate memory for 'point'
for no = 1:4

    %// ...
    point(no, :) = fscanf(FID5, '%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d',[9,1]);
    %// ...
end
```

The same goes for everything else you're reading with `fscanf` inside the loop. Preallocate an array before the loop for the data you read, and read it into a different row in each iteration.

Also, there's another bad mistake in your code:

```
no=fscanf(FID5, '%d', 1);  %// BAD! no' is used as the loop iteration variable
```

You're using the loop variable `no` inside the loop to store the data you read. That's a definite no-no! You should rather read the data into another variable (for example, `row_no`).

#### Is there a better solution?

However, this is way too cumbersome and not generic. Instead of the for loop and `fscanf`, consider using the powerful [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) command, like @fpe suggested:

```
C = textscan(FID5, '%d', 11);
row_no = cell2mat(C(2));
mode = cell2mat(C(2));
point = cell2mat(C(3:end));
```

Comment: Thank you. However,according to my expectation, point=size(no,9)  but just one line is printed.(1  1  1 2 3 10 17 16 15 8 9 )

Comment: @user2365201 I'm not sure what you're printing, and which solution you've chosen. The size of `point` should be 4-by-9 anyway.

Comment: I use for loop, I checked point's value in debugging satage, it is corrected.(size 4 by 9) however, there is no data in output file. Is it problem in fprint?

Comment: @user2365201 I think that in your `fprintf` command you need write to the corresponding row of each variable, for example `point(no, :)` (instead of `point`).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do just this:

```
format = repmat('%d',1,11);
fid = fopen(filename,'r');
A = textscan(fid,format,'Delimiter','\n');
```

Comment: each time program was implemented, input data read from data file.